# How can I integrate an airfoil plot into my lattice Boltzmann fluid flow simulation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to combine two sets of code - one that plots an airfoil with matplotlib, and the other that simulates a simple fluid flow.

I have everything set up except the implementation of the obstacle in the fluid (the airfoil).
So the way that it's meant to work is that each value in the grid has an either True or False value, with all points set to False by default. Any points that are 'True' will obstruct the fluid.

I'm finding it quite difficult to extract the coordinates from the airfoil plotter for a few reasons, one being that the airfoil coordinates are floats while the grid in the simulation is integers.

Just a disclaimer, I'm not that experienced with Python, sorry if my code is a bit messy - I've tried to add as many notes as possible.

Here is the method for the airfoil plot - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import math

#airfoil plot

digits = input("enter airfoil digits")                                      #extracting variables from input
m = float(str(digits)[0])
m = m/100
p = float(str(digits)[1])
p = p/10
xx = float(str(digits)[2:4])
xx = xx/100
nx = 300
ny = 75

plot_every = 100

def camber_line( x, m, p, c ):
    return np.where((x>=0)&(x<=(c*p)),
                    m * (x / np.power(p,2)) * (2.0 * p - (x / c)),
                    m * ((c - x) / np.power(1-p,2)) * (1.0 + (x / c) - 2.0 * p ))

def dyc_over_dx( x, m, p, c ):
    return np.where((x>=0)&(x<=(c*p)),
                    ((2.0 * m) / np.power(p,2)) * (p - x / c),
                    ((2.0 * m ) / np.power(1-p,2)) * (p - x / c ))

def thickness( x, xx, c ):                                                  #using NACA constants
    term1 =  0.2969 * (np.sqrt(x/c))
    term2 = -0.1260 * (x/c)
    term3 = -0.3516 * np.power(x/c,2)
    term4 =  0.2843 * np.power(x/c,3)
    term5 = -0.1015 * np.power(x/c,4)
    return 5 * xx * c * (term1 + term2 + term3 + term4 + term5)

def naca4(x, m, p, xx, c=1):
    dyc_dx = dyc_over_dx(x, m, p, c)
    th = np.arctan(dyc_dx)
    yt = thickness(x, xx, c)
    yc = camber_line(x, m, p, c)  
    return ((x - yt*np.sin(th), yc + yt*np.cos(th)), 
            (x + yt*np.sin(th), yc - yt*np.cos(th)))


x = np.linspace(0,300)





def main():
    nx = 300                                         #number of x cells
    ny = 75                                          #number of y cells
    tau = 0.53                                        #kinematic viscosity
    nt = 30000                                        #timesteps

                    #node speeds and weights
    

    nl = 9                                           #number of nodes
    x = np.linspace(nx,ny,nl)
    cxs = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1,-1,-1])   #discrete velocity x
    cys = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0,-1,-1, -1, 0, 1])   #discrete velocity y
    # these represent the position of each node relative to the central node
    # e.g, the top left node is "-1" in the x, and "1" in the y
    

    weights = np.array([4/9, 1/9, 1/36, 1/9, 1/36, 1/9, 1/36, 1/9, 1/36])
    # this is effectively the probability that a particle will travel to the position of each node
    
    

                    #initial conditions
    F = np.ones((ny, nx, nl)) + 0.01 * np.random.randn(ny, nx, nl)   
    # this adds the randomness to velocity at each node, so that the simulation isnt static

    F[:, :, 3] = 2.3
    
    # we want the fluid to be flowing to the right, so we set an initial velocity in the direction of the third node
    # (the third node is the one pointing right)

    grid = np.full([ny, nx], False)
    # creates an array that maps to every single cell in domain, each having a value of either true or false
    # if the value is false then it's considered empty space
    # if the value is true then that point is an obstacle
    
    # i want to set all coordinates from the airfoil as true in this array
    

    
    
        
                                                    #item[0] - x-coord     item[1] - y-coord
    

                #main loop
    
    for it in range(nt):
        print(it)

        # boundary conditions - making the walls absorb particles
        F[:, -1, [6, 7, 8]] = F[:, -2, [6, 7, 8]]                   # right wall
        F[:, 0, [2, 3, 4]] = F[:, 1, [2, 3, 4]]                     # left wall
        F[-1, :, [1, 2, 8]] = F[-2, :, [1, 2, 8]]                   # top wall
        F[0, :, [4, 5, 6]] = F[1, :, [4, 5, 6]]                     # bottom wall

        # setting the values at the  wall to the values of the cell next to it, making it cancel out
        
        for i, cx, cy in zip(range(nl), cxs, cys):  m 
            F[:, :, i] = np.roll(F[:, :, i], cx, axis = 1)
            F[:, :, i] = np.roll(F[:, :, i], cy, axis = 0)
    # while iterating through time, each cell (central node) gets 'rolled' in the direction of its corresponding discrete velocity

        
                
        bndryF = F[grid, :]
        bndryF = bndryF[:, [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
        #when hitting a boundary, the velocity is inverted, e.g if it was moving to the right node, it will now move to the left

                #fluid variables
        rho = np.sum(F, 2)
        # density is calculated as the sum of all the velocities within every single lattice

        ux = np.sum(F * cxs, 2) / rho
        uy = np.sum(F * cys, 2) / rho
        # x and y velocity is calulated by rearranging the momentum formula

                #applying boundary
        F[grid, :] = bndryF
        # the velocity at the cylinder is equal to the previously calculated inverse velocities 
        
        ux[grid] = 0
        uy[grid] = 0
        # within the airfoil the velocity is 0, no fluid movement inside a solid object

                # collision
        Feq = np.zeros(F.shape)
        for i, cx, cy, w in zip(range(nl), cxs, cys, weights):
            Feq[:, :, i] = rho * w * (
                1 + 3 * (cx*ux + cy*uy) + 9 * (cx*ux + cy*uy)**2 / 2 - 3 * (ux**2 + uy**2) / 2)
            # calculating the f equilibrium equation
            
        F = F + -(1/tau) * (F-Feq)
            # calculating the discretized equation, to solve for the next timestep

        if(it%plot_every == 0):
            pyplot.imshow(np.sqrt(ux**2 + uy**2))
            pyplot.pause(0.01)
            pyplot.cla()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: is this Buttle?

Comment: @Nin17 Sorry I'm not sure what Buttle is.